# criptografar e determinar tempo válido para url php

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso criptografar alguns parâmetros da url, como e-mail e código do cliente, e determinar o tempo válido para o link encaminhado.

Me espelhei no Facebook, Google e Twitter que usam essa metodologia para garantir a segurança da url.

Qual seria a melhor criptografia, MD5, SHA1, base64 nesse caso especifico?
Qual a melhor forma para determinar o tempo válido para o link?

Comment: Você pode usar este artigo como sua resposta.
http://www.nacaolivre.com.br/php/criptografia-aes-em-objeto-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá 
**MD5 e SHA1** são algoritmos de `HASH`, não são criptografia. Quando você criptografa algo, provavelmente precisará descriptografar no futuro. Algoritmos de `HASH` são one-way e não é possível obter o texto original a partir de um HASH com métodos comuns (força bruta sim poderia resolver, mas sabemos que não é computacionalmente viável).
**Base64** é simplesmente uma codificação diferente. Pegamos um texto, alteramos a codificação do mesmo, mas ainda é a mesma informação.
 
Segundo o que você propôs, o HASH evitaria que uma pessoa descobrisse a senha de um jeito fácil, mas ainda exporia o seu HASH que é de fato o que o sistema vai usar para fazer a autenticação. Mesmo que não passe isso na URL é muito simples obter o conteúdo de uma requisição. Mas qual a solução então?
Quando o servidor utiliza protocolos seguros para transmissão de dados ele de fato implementa criptografia nos dados trafegados. Geralmente acessamos sites utilizando os protocolos HTTP ou **HTTPS**. O HTTP não oferece segurança, já o HTTPS adiciona uma camada de proteção através de SSL/TLS, dessa forma os dados enviados e recebidos são criptografados e somente o cliente e o servidor conseguem entender as informações.